# Polite/nice way to ask for a language exchange partner

Tags: politeness, english-to-japanese

> 日本の言語パートナーを探して。

Is what I currently came up with but I think it is much to direct.
I want to express something like this:
"I would be very pleased to find a Japanese language exchange partner" (meaning a male or female, native speaker)

Comment: You'd be surprised at how directly you could ask this, especially on an open forum.  ランゲージエクスチェンジパートナーを探しています will suffice. 言語交換をしたいですが would also work fine.

Comment: Never heard ランゲージエクスチェンジパートナー used, but I agree that you could use 言語交換をしたいですが・・・ as a very good option. Probably what I would have said. I trust that most of the others looking for an english exchange will be very friendly and talk to you just with that. 日本の言語パートナーを探してdoens't make a whole lot of sense. It seems like a translation from English, and isn't fully coherent.

Comment: 言語交換をしたいんですが probably better than without ん

Comment: Sqrtbottle could you make this an answer so I can accept it? It seems to be the best option indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say

「日本語を教えてくださる方を探しています。代わりに英語(or French or Russian? I don't know what your mother tongue is.) をお教えします。男性でも女性でも構いません。」